# floating point system

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point, rounding-error

Need to check my answer which I'm not confident about my solution. The question based on Floating point systems, Roundoff Error. Please correct me if you think my answers are wrong, my question is on image capture here.

[image]

(a)

fl(x) = (4/10^1 + 3/10^2 + 1/10^3 + 2/10^4) * 10^1 = 0.4312*10^1

fl(y) = (4/10^1 + 3/10^2 + 1/10^3 + 2/10^4) * 10^0 = 0.4312*10^0

(b)

n = 1/2*B^(1-t) = 1/2*(10)^1-4 = 0.0005

(c)

Overflow  = B^(U+1) *(1-B^-t)  = 10^4*(1-10^-4) = 9999

Underflow = B^(L) = 10^-3 = 0.001

Thus (C) 12000 is Overflow  and (D) -12000 is Underflow

=== Solution Done ===

Looking to hear from you ... Thank you

Comment: Welcome! Please use Mathjax instead of images. Why on earth should D be an underflow? -12000 is not near zero!

Comment: Is this maths or computer science?

Comment: Hello, gammatester; I've lacked of understanding the idea of underflow and overflow. If it was a wrong, then how i could reach to correct choice. Thank you

Comment: Hello,  badjohn; This's Math Numerical Analysis. Thank you